# Channels first format in TensorFlow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, computer-vision, tensorflow.js

I am converting https://github.com/Richard-An/StyleNAS to a browser compatible model. I am using TensorFlow.js. Due to some issues in the conversion libraries (https://github.com/nerox8664/pytorch2keras), I want to keep the model in `channels_first` (NCHW) format.

I know TensorFlow.js supports this. I can successfully import my model in the desired format. But I have a problem with data. When I convert the images to tensors via https://js.tensorflow.org/api/2.7.0/#browser.fromPixels they are always in `channels_last` (NHWC) format. Is there a way I can explicitly change this? I am new to TensorFlow.js and I couldn't find any answers for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The axis can be swapped

HWC -> CHW (for a 3d tensor)

```
tensor.transpose([2, 0, 1])
```

NHWC -> NCHW (for a 4d tensor)

```
tensor.transpose([0, 3, 1, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't thought it would be this straightforward! For NHWC, I suppose you mean `[0,3,1,2]` right?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I will edit the question